# How to build nexe for MIPS architecture running Linux?

Tags: linux, google-nativeclient

I'm investigating the possibility of transition from npapi to **ppapi** for our product, which is supposed to use QtWebengine in future.

The target platform being MISP Linux.

As it turns out, to use ppapi you've got to use naclsdk as well. So I followed the [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/download) and after I ran

> './naclsdk list'

the toolchain directory of contained these directories:

> linux_arm_newlib  linux_pnacl  linux_x86_glibc  linux_x86_newlib

no support for MISP if I'm not mistaken...

But how can I build nexe (not pexe) **ppapi** plugin for MISP architecture with Linux? The naclsdk documentation says it's possible.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

MIPS is supported by ImgTech: the NaCl team accepts patches from them to support MIPS, and we have some tests bots, but we don't build a full MIPS toolchain and haven't done a thorough security audit (though we've done pretty extensive code review). You'll have to [build the toolchain](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/developing-pnacl) to get MIPS support. You'll want to run `./toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py` as explained on that page, and run the MIPS build (this will give you the PNaCl toolchain). You may want to try out `nacl-clang` for MIPS, which at the moment may not be fully functional, or look at the [design document](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/issues/detail?id=3946) for `nacl-clang` which explains how to build a `.pexe` and translate it to a `.nexe`.

Comment: Thank you. I built the toolchain and built pexe with it and translated it to mips. But I'm not sure it will work on all the embedded target systems. The build process is too obscure. Now I'm considering CEF3. But thank you very much.